# Saving audio played via AUFilePlayer to an external file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-audio

In my iOS app, I am playing some short wave files and finally trying to export everything that I played to a single audio file such as WAV or CAF file. I have managed to do the playback using AUFilePlayer. How do I save the audio played via AUFilePlayer to a WAV or CAF file?

Comment: I am stuck setting up the AUGraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to look into the ExtAudioFile API. This exposes a function called `ExtAudioFileWrite` which is designed to tie in nicely with the data your Audio Units are passing around. ExtAudioFileWrite's signature is as follows:

```
OSStatus ExtAudioFileWrite (
   ExtAudioFileRef        inExtAudioFile,
   UInt32                 inNumberFrames,
   const AudioBufferList  *ioData
);
```

Which coincides nicely with an Audio Unit render callback, which looks like this:

```
OSStatus (*AURenderCallback)(
    void * inRefCon,
    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags * ioActionFlags,
    const AudioTimeStamp * inTimeStamp,
    UInt32 inBusNumber,
    UInt32 inNumberFrames,
    AudioBufferList * ioData
);
```

Notice the shared `UInt32 inNumberFrames` and `AudioBufferList * ioData` args.

So, your workflow could be:

1. Get an ExtAudioFile set up for writing
2. Get your AUGraph set up to render audio
3. Capture the AudioBufferLists that your AudioUnits are passing around

3 requires a bit more knowledge of how your app is set up, so I can't really help you out too much there. If you want to have your audio going to the speakers as well as being written to a file, you'll probably want to make use of `AUGraphAddRenderNotify`, which will let you know whenever a render happens (and let you hook in your own AURenderCallback to write to your ExtAudioFile).

If you're doing things this way (i.e. live in a render callback) make sure to use `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync` so you don't block the render thread.